# Java: "non-static method drawRect" error

Tags: java, drawrect

I am really new in Java. Thought I had figure some stuff out by now, but I have a problem that proves otherwise!

Ok! Here it is. I have this code (Edited - Not original):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyClass extends HisClass
{
    public void drawRectangle(int width, int height)
    {
      int x1 = this.getXPos();
      int y1 = this.getYPos();
      java.awt.Graphics.drawRect(x1, y1, width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      AnotherClass theOther = new AnotherClass();
      MyClass mine = new MyClass(theOther);
      mine.move();
    }
}
```

The error it gives me is this:

```
MyClass.java:66: error: non-static method drawRect(int,int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Can you please provide me with a solution?
It would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is HisClass? Is it a component?

Comment: Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.awt.Graphics.drawRect(x1, y1, width, height);
```

`drawRect` method is not static.. You should get an instance of your Graphics class somehow to use it: -

```
(graphicsInstance).drawRect(x1, y1, width, height);
```

Since `Graphics` class is `abstract`, so you need to find appropriate way to instantiate your Graphics object, to get `graphicsInstance`

You can use `GraphicsContext` to draw whatever you want to.. GraphicsContext is an object belonging to `Graphics` class which you can use to `drawRect()`

**See these post. Might be useful: -**

[How do I initialize a Graphics object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965347/how-do-i-intialize-a-graphics-object-in-java)

[what is a graphics context (In Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000961/what-is-a-graphics-context-in-java)

Comment: I think Graphics is an abstract class.

Comment: @LewsTherin.. Yeah I saw that.. I didn't knew that that's why I wrote assumption there..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried similar solutions, but gives the error: MyClass.java:66: error: Graphics is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Like Lews commented...

Comment: @RohitJain quite right. But he doesn't need to instanciate it. Using awt, you have usually a "Graphics-Context" given as a method parameter on which you can call drawXXX-methods. He has to find out where to get it.

Comment: Ok! I thought it would be much more simpler to achieve what I was trying to. I did a lot of searching and didn't find what I was looking for. The thing is that I am very restricted because this is a project with very specific instructions. So I can't just start creating classes or doing it in a complicated way with JFrame.

Comment: Anyway! Thank you all for your help! Really appreciated!
Rohit Jain, I'll just pick your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code that draws a `Rectangle` using `drawRect()` onto the `JPanel` by overriding its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and adding it to the `JFrame`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawRect extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //draw our rect
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 50);
    }

    //or else we wont see the JPanel
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("DrawRect");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawRect());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```